# Can't use EF Core's Fluent API OnDelete method: "does not contain a definition for OnDelete"

Tags: .net, entity-framework-core

I am trying to use EF Core's Fluent API `OnDelete` method to delete dependent entities when a parent entity is deleted, as shown [here](https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/configuration/fluent-api/ondelete-method).

I'm trying to do the following in my `DbContext` class:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Product>()
        .HasOne(u => u.Nutrition)
        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Delete);
    }
}
```

And this is where I've been stuck for hours, because I get that annoying red squiggly line under `OnDelete` and `DeleteBehavior` with the two error messages below.

> 'ReferenceNavigationBuilder<Product, Nutrition>' does not contain a
> definition for 'OnDelete' and no accessible extension method
> 'OnDelete' accepting a first argument of type
> 'ReferenceNavigationBuilder<Product, Nutrition>'
> could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
> reference?)

> 'DeleteBehavior' does not contain a definition for 'Delete'

This is what my model looks like:

```
public class Product
{
    [Key]
    public int ProductId { get; set; }

    public string ProductName { get; set; }

    public string ProductType { get; set; }

    public Nutrition ProductNutrition { get; set; }
}

public class Nutrition
{
    [Key]
    public int NutritionId { get; set; }

    public string Ingredients { get; set; }
}
```

When I put my cursor over `modelBuilder.Entity`, I see that it's a `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Builders.EntityTypeBuilder`. When I look at the documentation for that class here, I don't see an `OnDelete` method. What am I doing wrong? How is everyone else casually using the `OnDelete` method without issue?

Here's the list of packages in my project:

- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore (3.1.4)
- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Abstractions (3.1.4)
- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational (3.1.4)
- Npgsql (4.1.3.1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out.

The `OnDelete` method is only available for the `WithOne` and `WithMany` methods. In other words, it's necessary to use the Has/With pattern when defining relationships, as explained here: https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/configuration/fluent-api/hasone-method

So... before I could do anything else, I had to go back and change my `Nutrition` class to include a reference back to the parent class, like so:

```
public class Nutrition
{
    [Key]
    public int NutritionId { get; set; }

    public string Ingredients { get; set; }

    public Product Product { get; set; } //added this
}
```

And then in my `OnModelCreating` method, I could do this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Product>()
    .HasOne(a => a.ProductNutrition)
    .WithOne(b => b.Product)
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
```

That defines a one-to-one relationship between Product and Nutrition, and now it lets me use the `OnDelete` method to set a `DeleteBehavior`.